Tilde not expanded correctly when compiling install4j called from a Jenkinsfile groovy script inside a container
I'm seeing this in the log:
[WARNING] The JDK with name "JDK 1.8" has not been configured in this install4j installation
(config file /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/trunk_ci/?/.config/install4j/v10/config.xml)

I've seen a similar path in the past when we didn't yet use a custom local maven repo:
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository

output:
'/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/trunk_ci/?/.m2/repository'

I'm not sure if the solution is to configure the container image differently or adjust the Jenkinsfile script or if install4j should maybe replace usages of ~ with java.home property or HOME env variable (if used at all of course).
The output happens from within a 'withMaven'-section, similar to this:
withMaven(mavenSettingsConfig: '...', mavenOpts: '...', mavenLocalRepo: '...') {
      sh "mvn clean package -e -U -B -ntp -Dinstall4j.disableSigning"
}


You could copy the config file to the config directory in install4j installation directory. Then that config file will be used instead of a user-specific config file.

It looks like that specific warning came from <application jdkName="JDK 1.8">. I deleted that attribute as I couldn't find it in newer install4j files.
